# Is it possible construct a well-defined series through integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I have a function $$G=\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^x\mathrm{d}z\,g(z)}~.$$
If $f(x)$ was unity, the above integral could have been easily written as $$G=1-\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)}~.$$
Now, for a general $f(x)$ reducing this into something simpler is not apparent to me. But, I have an idea on which I am stuggling: carrying out integration by parts infinite times to construct a series, which possibly reduces to something exponential. The approach:
\begin{align}
G=\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)}\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x)+\int_0^Sg(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^x\mathrm{d}z\,g(z)}\int_0^x\mathrm{d}y\,f(y)g(y)\\
=\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)}\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x)+\int_0^Sg(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^x\mathrm{d}z\,g(z)}\int_0^x\mathrm{d}y\,f(y)g(y)\\
=\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)}\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x)+\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)}\int_0^Sg(x)\int_0^x\mathrm{d}y\,f(y)g(y)+\int_0^Sg(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^x\mathrm{d}z\,g(z)}\int_0^{x}\mathrm{d}y_1g(y_1)\int_0^{y_1}\mathrm{d}y_2\,f(y_2)g(y_2)~.\\
\end{align}
At this point, it seems like there is some pattern. The final answer is desired to be in the form of $$G=\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)}\times\text{function}\left(\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x)\right),$$
or something similar. Any ideas on how to complete this idea?

Addition:
Letting $$K(S)=\int_0^S\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)g(x),$$
The entire problem can be reduced to finding an appropriate representation for the following sum:
$$K(S)+\int_0^Sg(x)K(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^Sg(x)\left(\int_0^xg(x')K(x')\mathrm{d}x'\right)\mathrm{d}x+\cdots$$

Comment: Why do you put the $dx$, $dz$, etc. in front of the function?  Is that normal?

Comment: Well, it is normal in Physics. But, my intention here is the same as $dx$ being at the end of the integral, if you like.

Comment: That's fine, in math you always put it at the end, but I guess it doesn't matter.